# How to turn on Diagnostic Full-text Query for Cosmos Db with ARM template, CLI or PowerShell

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, diagnostics

I need to turn on Cosmos Db Diagnostic Full-text Query as part of deployment pipeline. Ideally would prefer this being part of ARM template, if not then CLI or PowerShell would do. Couldn't find any documentation on this, has anybody had it done?
I also had exported ARM template for the Cosmos Db account with this setting On in portal, couldn't find anything relevant in the template so redeployed the template and the setting was Off when deployed.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-monitor-resource-logs#create-diagnostic-setting-via-azure-cli ?

Comment: This will probably get you close on an ARM Template. Unfortunately they don't have a sample for Cosmos but you could create this using the az cli command above (or Azure Portal), then Export the template for that resource from the portal. From there find the values for Cosmos logs you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/diagnosticsettings?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template

Comment: I've seen these links but couldn't find anything helpful for the specific setting I need, would you be able to point me to something concrete? I also (going to update the post) have exported ARM template for the Cosmos Db account with this setting On in portal, couldn't find anything relevant in the template so redeployed the template and the setting was Off when deployed .

Answer (score 0):

I've found a setting `enableFullTextQuery` in a preview version of the ARM template for the cosmos account which worked for my cosmos db account: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/2022-08-15-preview/databaseaccounts?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template#diagnosticlogsettings

Sample snippet:

```
resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2022-08-15-preview' = {
  name: 'string'
  location: 'string'
  properties: {
    diagnosticLogSettings: {
      enableFullTextQuery: 'True'
    }
}
```